# error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int **'

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#ifndef _grid_h
#define _grid_h

#include<string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class grid{
    T** main;

public:

    grid<T>(){}


    grid<T>(int col, int row){  
        main = new T[col];          //<-this line gives me error C2440:
                                    //'=' : cannot convert from 'int *' to 'int **'
        for(int i =0;i<col;i++)
            main[i]=new T[row];
    }
};

#endif
```

I want to create my own version of the Grid class. Basically I want to save the information in a 2 dimensional array of T. I think this is the most efficient way to do it. Now How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would need to be

```
main = new T*[col];
```

Because `main` is an array of pointers to `T`. But there are better ways to create a two-dimensional array, for example

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> main(col, std::vector<T>(row));
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate an array of correct type: use `main = new T*[col];` instead of `main = new T[col];`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your last code line:

```
main[i]=new T[row];
```

For that to work, `main[i]` needs to be a pointer. But you tried to create `main` as a `new T[col]` - an array of `T`s. It needs to be an array of pointers-to-`T`.

```
main = new T*[col]; // Create an array of pointers
```